# How to make React input a text and select?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am trying to make my react-bootstrap form-control/input to allow both text and select. So, when an user clicks on the input box, the user have the options to type the values themselves, or select one of the options that popup when input box is clicked. I am using this as my form (https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/).

I was able to get it working by using autoComplete and datalist:

```
<Form.Group as={Col}>
    <Form.Label>Number</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control id="number" name="number" list="numberList"
                   autoComplete="new-password" value={number} onChange={this.handleChange}>
    </Form.Control>
    <datalist id="numberList">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </datalist>
</Form.Group>
```

However, I was wondering if there's a different way to achieve this.

Comment: im confused on what it is you're trying to achieve

Comment: Why doesn't datalist work? What's the problem with it? It's not really clear.

Comment: @BARNOWL I apologize for the confusion. I am trying to make a input box where users have options to either enter the value themselves when input box is clicked or click on the values that popup when that input box is clicked.

Comment: @Train I apologize for the confusion. Datalist works. I was just wondering if there's a different way to do this.

Comment: There are a lot of libraries which provide something like this e.g. [react-autocomplete](https://github.com/reactjs/react-autocomplete/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

```
<Form.Group>
                    <Form.Label>Address</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                      list="pharmacyList"
                      // defaultValue="pharmacyName"
                      {...register("pharmacyLocation")}
                      onChange={(e) => e.target.event}
                      placeholder="Select Address"
                    ></Form.Control>
                    <datalist id="pharmacyList">
                      {patientPharmacy?.allPatientPharmacyData?.map((item) => (
                        <option
                          key={item?.pharmacyId}
                          value={item?.pharmacyLocation}
                        >
                          {item.pharmacyLocation}
                        </option>
                      ))}
                    </datalist>
                  </Form.Group>
```

Comment: To help people understand your answer better, please provide some extra information along with the code you shared.